# Changing height of status bar in wxpython on mac?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm writing an app in python using the wxPython gui library for the mac, and finding that you can't change the height of a window status bar, even though there is a function setMinHeight() function in the wxPython library.

According to [this reference](http://comp.soft-sys.wxwindows.narkive.com/kDvqMJSq/is-wxstatusbar-setminheight-implemented-on-wxmac), setMinHeight isn't implemented for OSX. Is there a workaround that might allow for changing the height of the status bar?

Answer (score 0):

From playing around with StatusBar on OSX, it seems like changing the status bar height using the built-in class is impossible. I also tried the highly customizable [EnhancedStatusBar](http://wiki.wxpython.org/EnhancedStatusBar) class, but despite all its effort, the size remains unchanged because it still relies on the SetMinHeight method of the wxPython StatusBar.

The only hope that I can see (and from a few minutes of playing around it doesn't seem too difficult) is to create a custom "StatusBar-like" object. On OSX, this shouldn't be more than a horizontal line and some text at the bottom of your window. If you're planning to make the program cross-platform, you can do some OS detection to determine whether or not to use the built-in StatusBar class or your custom one.

I hope this helps.